# How to change reference level for covariates in latent class analysis using glca package in R?

Tags: r, coefficients

I'm using the glca package in R to estimate a latent class model with covariates. In the table of covariate coefficients, the reference value for the regiao variable is set to CENTRO-OESTE, but I would like to set it to SUDESTE.

However, I can't seem to find any argument in the glca function to set the reference levels for each covariate. I checked the package documentation at https://kim0sun.github.io/glca/index.html, but there's no mention of how to do this.

Here is an example of the coefficient table:

```
                                    Odds Ratio Coefficient  Std. Error  t value
(Intercept)                             2.8047      1.0313      0.5850    1.763
sexoM                                   1.1808      0.1662      0.1864    0.892
regiaoNORDESTE                          0.4893     -0.7147      0.4752   -1.504
regiaoNORTE                             0.2707     -1.3068      0.6937   -1.884
regiaoSUDESTE                           0.5940     -0.5209      0.4273   -1.219
regiaoSUL                               0.6329     -0.4575      0.4557   -1.004
gde_areaCiências Biológicas             1.9771      0.6816      0.3534    1.929
gde_areaCiências da Saúde               0.6264     -0.4677      0.3312   -1.412
gde_areaCiências Exatas e da Terra      1.8469      0.6135      0.3687    1.664
gde_areaCiências Humanas                0.5270     -0.6405      0.3110   -2.060
gde_areaCiências Sociais Aplicadas      0.5824     -0.5406      0.3591   -1.505
gde_areaEngenharias                     1.4810      0.3927      0.3889    1.010
gde_areaLingüística, Letras e Artes     0.8935     -0.1126      0.4627   -0.243
gde_areaOutra                           0.5580     -0.5834      0.5493   -1.062
cat_nivel1B                             1.5110      0.4128      0.4167    0.990
cat_nivel1C                             1.2448      0.2190      0.3806    0.575
cat_nivel1D                             1.1694      0.1565      0.3399    0.460
cat_nivel2                              1.8092      0.5929      0.2991    1.982
cat_nivelSR                             1.2244      0.2025      0.7557    0.268
                                     Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                            0.0781 .
sexoM                                  0.3726  
regiaoNORDESTE                         0.1328  
regiaoNORTE                            0.0598 .
regiaoSUDESTE                          0.2231  
regiaoSUL                              0.3155  
gde_areaCiências Biológicas            0.0540 .
gde_areaCiências da Saúde              0.1581  
gde_areaCiências Exatas e da Terra     0.0963 .
gde_areaCiências Humanas               0.0396 *
gde_areaCiências Sociais Aplicadas     0.1325  
gde_areaEngenharias                    0.3127  
gde_areaLingüística, Letras e Artes    0.8078  
gde_areaOutra                          0.2883  
cat_nivel1B                            0.3221  
cat_nivel1C                            0.5651  
cat_nivel1D                            0.6454  
cat_nivel2                             0.0476 *
cat_nivelSR                            0.7888  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution found was to assign the desired reference value using the relevel function:

`factors <- relevel(factors, ref = 'SUDESTE')`